# SVG not rendering correcly in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, polygon

I'm utilizing a polygon background in a site I'm working on where I want the height to stay at 400px and the angle to stay at 7% regardless of how you resize it. I got this working with the following code:

```
<div style="width:100%;max-width:100%;margin-top:-0px;position:absolute;top:40px;overflow:hidden;background-color:rgba(155,0,0,0);">
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div id="backgroundImage1" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <svg width="4000" viewBox="0 0 4000 1200" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <polygon points="0,0 0,400 4000,900 4000,500" style="fill:#525252;stroke:#525252;stroke-width:0;" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick that I'm using it making it hang off the edge of the screen (out to 4000px) and hoping they never make a monitor that wide.

The problem I'm running into is that this renders perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but breaks in IE. It seems to scale the polygon to fit the screen there. Anyone know some to fix this IE compatibility issue?

**JS Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/z81cxyjw/
Compare the following in IE & Chrome to see what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN about viewBox:

> The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers min-x, min-y, width and height, separated by whitespace and/or a comma, which specify a rectangle in user space which should be mapped to the bounds of the **viewport** established by the given element, taking into account attribute preserveAspectRatio.

Apparently IE has problem with figuring out viewport. Add `height` property and/or specify `viewPort` property - this works at least in IE11, I haven't checked in other versions.

```html
    <div style="width:100%;max-width:100%;margin-top:-0px;position:absolute;top:40px;overflow:hidden;background-color:rgba(155,0,0,0);">
        <div style="position:relative">
            <div id="backgroundImage1" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <svg width="4000" height="1200" viewPort="0 0 4000 1200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    
                    <polygon points="0,0 0,400 4000,900 4000,500" style="fill:#525252;stroke:#525252;stroke-width:0;" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. Fixed the compatibility issue perfectly!